typedef for constant pointer to constant data function array
I have a C header file (.h):
typedef uint8_t paraFunction(uint8_t paraVal, uint8_t paraNum);
paraFunction *paraCallTable[256];

And I have a C source file (.c):
paraFunction *paraCallTable[] = {   fn1, fn2, ... fn255, fn256 };

However, the array ends up in the data section. I want it to be in code/flash because the function addresses (the array data) are constant. The array is used by functions in other source files.
How do I rewrite these declarations to make it all constant? And where do they need to be (.c or .h)?
I googled and tried a gazillion different ways and I obviously just don't get it.

"the array ends up in the data section" Why does that matter?

@dbush Because I only have 24K of SRAM to work with (CPU is a STM32F373CB). And I need to get constants out of SRAM so that all the variables will fit in SRAM.

paraFunction *const paraCallTable[]?

Making it constant won't necessarily be sufficient to have it located in flash. Doing that is platform and tool-chain specific. You might need to get into linker settings and possibly a small assembly file.

@AviBerger Perhaps, but it's probably the first step.

@Barmar, Agreed.

I guess I could define a new section (ConstArray) in the linker file that puts the array into flash (after using something like attribute((section(".ConstantArray"))) on the array declaration). I've done that when declaring functions that need to go into SRAM. But I would have thought that defining the array as a constant would have put it into flash /code section automagically. Otherwise, what's the point of the "const" verb when applied to variables?

It usually puts it into the text section, similar to the code. If your compiler puts code into flash, it will probably do what you want.

@Barmar - paraFunction *const paraCallTable[] works great! I swear I tried that. I feel like a complete idiot.

@Katoomba maybe you tried paraFunction const *paraCallTable[] or const paraFunction *paraCallTable[]? It has different semantics than paraFunction *const paraCallTable[].

@freestyle I am sure you're right. Either way, my problem is quite solved. Now I need to go read some more to (re)learn the semantics.

@Katoomba: The rule is simple. If you write const before the *, then you are specifying that the object to which the pointer points is const. If you instead write the const after the *, then you are specifying that the pointer itself is const.

Since you are already using the clearest (IMHO) form of function pointer typedef, it's simply a matter of adding const to the declaration at the right side of the *, like you would with an object pointer you'd like to end up in ROM:
paraFunction *const paraCallTable[]

Had you used the form typedef uint8_t (*paraFunction)(uint8_t paraVal, uint8_t paraNum); then you'd have to use the far less obvious and confusing form const paraFunction paraCallTable[]. This is a read-only pointer to data, not read-only data or pointer to read-only data as one might think.
This is a solid argument for sticking to the good typedef style you are already using.
We may also note that it's good practice to always declare function pointer tables as * const, ROM or no ROM, since changing function pointers in run-time is most often undesired.

Thank you for the concise and additional explanation.
